# VS Code seems to be compiling my server into my local working directory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm using the PERN stack. Whenever I run `node app` the server appears in my working directory. It doesn't close after I use `crtl+c` to kill the process.

Here are some pictures:

[Compiling and killing the express server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEdKo.png)

[This extension-less file appears sharing the same name as the port I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNQTL.png)

[This is what happens when I try to restart the express server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWIV0.png)

[After deleting the file '3005', I can restart the server successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQEEx.png)

Here is how I initialize an instance of my express server.

```
SERVER_PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Server is running. Listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

I am trying to teach myself the PERN stack so it's nothing complex. This problem just started earlier this week. I cannot figure out a solution. I don't even know how to google for this problem.

It's worth mentioning that my front-end can no longer communicate with my backend. Hopefully these symptoms can help diagnose the problem because it has severely hindered my project this past week.

I tried reinstalling VS code thinking it may be a bug. I also tried a bunch of different methods of ensuring the server gets killed when I hit 'ctrl+c' but none of them worked.

Comment: This comes up so often it should have its own close-vote. Remove any `;` from your `.env` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like whatever is setting `process.env.SERVER_PORT` is including a `;` semi-colon at the end of your `SERVER_PORT`, which should not be the case.

Notice in your screenshot the server is saying:

`Server is running. Listening on port 3005;`

The code here contains no `;` within the string which means you're setting that as part of your PORT which is likely the issue.

```
console.log(`Server is running. Listening on port ${SERVER_PORT}`);
```

Review your `.env` files for any extraneous semi-colons and remove them. It's purely line-delimited.